# How to connect existing key pair to a running ElasticBeanstalk EC2 using AWS CLI or EB CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I've created a key pair. How can I connect the existing key pair to a running Elastic Beanstalk EC2 using AWS CLI or EB CLI?

Answer (score 0):

When you say, you are using beanstalk for deploying your application you are using kind of PASS platform.
1)Why you want to log into ec2 running under elastic beanstalk?
==> if you check the logs check following link
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html

==> if you want to install anything then its not the way how beanstalk works or its not right way to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If the EC2 instance was created through Elastic Beanstalk, you can perform `eb ssh --setup`, which is an EBCLI command, to associate a keypair with it.